# How do I make the DOM load fully before Javascript functions execute?

Tags: javascript, html

Good day All,

I trying to append to an HTML body but I am receiving the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined
at Object.setDStorageIframe (siqnewchatwindow_54070f598ef9af5a609d9bc4e251b4d9_.js:1)
at HTMLIFrameElement.e.onload (floatbutton_acd56171301bf02d890bd9f348e00b8e_.js:1)

If I understand correctly it is because the javascript executes before the html can load on the page?

My full html code is as follows:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button  class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Go to unit
      </button>
      <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
        <li>Unit</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Javascript code:

```
ZOHO.CREATOR.init()
.then(function(data) {
var queryParams = ZOHO.CREATOR.UTIL.getQueryParams();
            var config = {
            reportName : "All_Units", 
            id : queryParams.development_id,
            criteria : "(Development == " + id + ")",
        }
    return config;
        }
    )
    .then((config) => {
        ZOHO.CREATOR.API.getAllRecords(config)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log("Executing API Function...");
            console.log(response.data);
            var unit = {
              unitNo : "Unit_Number"
            }
            $('#dropdown').append(
              '<div>' + unitNO +'</div>'
            );
})
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: JavaScript does not need to have the DOM fully loaded in order to manipulate it. It just needs that whatever specific elements you're using have already been defined. Your JavaScript code comes at the end of the document [all of it?], so that shouldn't be the issue, not at least directly. Perhaps you want to rephrase your question as a Zoho specific subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to load event on the window object, and execute any codes after that.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  // execute the rest of the code
});
```